# Is there a way to get latitude longitude constantly updated without running Google MAPS app in emulators backgroud

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation, location

Is there a way to get latitude longitude constantly updated without running Google MAPS app in emulators background.  I would like to receive updated latitude and longitude from the users device. The code gets the latitude and longitude only after I change between apps or setup a driving route and press the button. I would like to update every X amount of time.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button bt_Location;
    TextView tv_nearStopName, tv_nextBusIDtoNearStop;
    EditText txtinput_busID;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    LocationHelper locationHelper;
    User user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //assign variables
        bt_Location = findViewById(R.id.bt_checkIN);
        tv_nearStopName = findViewById(R.id.tv_stopName);
        tv_nextBusIDtoNearStop = findViewById(R.id.tv_nextBusID);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this);
        txtinput_busID = findViewById(R.id.txtinput_busID);

        //if not get location permissions...
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            user = new User(0.0,0.0);
            getCurrentLocation();
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1000);
        }

      bt_Location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              getCurrentLocation()
            }
        });
    }//end onCreate



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            getCurrentLocation();
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1000);
        }
    } 

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 100 && grantResults.length > 0 && (grantResults[0] + grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            getCurrentLocation();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getCurrentLocation() {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                    Location location = task.getResult();
                    //check condition
                    if (location != null){
                        //initialize user object
                        user.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
                        user.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
                        tv_nextBusIDtoNearStop.setText(String.valueOf(user.getLongitude()));
                    }else {
                        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).setInterval(1000).setFastestInterval(100).setNumUpdates(1);
                        LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                                Log.d("DEBUGGING:     ", "onLocationResult executing....");
                                Location location1 = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                                user.setLatitude(location1.getLatitude());
                                user.setLongitude(location1.getLongitude());
                               // tvLatitude.setText(String.valueOf(user.getLatitude()));
                                tv_nextBusIDtoNearStop.setText(String.valueOf(user.getLongitude()));
                            }
                        };
     locationReqeuest, locaitoncallback, Looper.MyLooper()
                        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                    }
                }
            });
        }else {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        }
    }//end getCurrentLocation


}
```

Comment: `in emulators background. ` AND `from the users device.` ? Unclear what you want where.

Comment: Ignoring the "emulator" part you should request location updates if you want a constantly updating location. The `getLastLocation()` just returns what happens to be the last known location and does in no way trigger an update process of the location data. Google Maps running in the background does request location updates which causes the "last known location" to be something meaningful.